# display full phth of file in netbeanse IDE

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I want to display full file path in my netbeanse IDE in toolbar I have seen this in PC I tried a lot but is is not displaying

I don't want to just display I want to copy direct file path from there 
Uploading[image] a snap for understanding what I want

[image]

Thanks in advance 
Netbeanse giving this functionality I know but forgot that how to enable this

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl + Alt + L` ? `Ctrl + Alt + L` copies the fully qualified path into the clipboard. Make sure the editor window has the focus.

Comment: @ShaggyInjun not working

Comment: Sorry try "Alt + Shift + L". That works.

Comment: No sir ....not working alt+shift+L

Comment: Check out my answer. If still are not getting what you want, could u revisit your question and add a bit more detail about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Alt + Shift + L` will copy the path of the currently active file to clipboard. You can then paste this in any where else. I use this regularly and know it works.

If you want to show the path of the file in the toolbar location like in the image you have uploaded above, you may have to write your own plugin. Here are a couple of plugins that do this already.

[path tools](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/676/path-tools)
[show path in title](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/42000/show-path-in-title)

Comment: Sir You are absolutely right , but it is working in netbeans 7.4 version and what is my Mistake I am using 7.2.1 version